# Progressively filter/smooth a signal in python (to straight line on the left to no filtering on the right)

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing, smoothing

A picture is worth a thousand words (sorry for the shoddy work):

[image: Example of filtering]

If the solution is preserving the value and the slope at both ends it is better.
If, in addition, the position and sharpness of the transition can be adjusted it is perfect.

But I have not found any solution yet...

Thank you very much for your help

Here is a piece of code to get started:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import numpy as np 

def round_up_to_odd(f):
    return np.int(np.ceil(f / 2.) * 2 + 1)

def generateRandomSignal(n=1000, seed=None):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    n : integer, optional
        Number of points in the signal. The default is 1000.

    Returns
    -------
    sig : numpy array

    """
    np.random.seed(seed)
    print("Seed was:", seed)
    steps = np.random.choice(a=[-1, 0, 1], size=(n-1))
    roughSig = np.concatenate([np.array([0]), steps]).cumsum(0)
    sig = savgol_filter(roughSig, round_up_to_odd(n/20), 6)
    return sig

n = 1000
t = np.linspace(0,10,n)
seed = np.random.randint(0,high=100000)
#seed = 45136
sig = generateRandomSignal(seed=seed)

###############################
# ????
# sigFilt = adaptiveFilter(sig)
###############################

# Plot
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, sig, label="Signal")
# plt.plot(t, sigFilt, label="Signal filtered")
plt.legend()
```

Comment: I am just wondering if my answer below is helpful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple convolution does smoothing. However, as mentioned below, here we need strong smoothing first and no smoothing towards the end. I used the moving average approach with the dynamic size of the window. In the example below, the window size changes linearly.

```
def dynamic_smoothing(x, start_window_length=(len(x)//2), end_window_length=1):
    d_sum = np.cumsum(a, dtype=float)
    smoothed = list()
    for i in range(len(x)):
        # compute window length
        a = i / len(x)
        w = int(np.round(a * start_window_length + (1.0-a) * end_window_length))
        # get the window
        w0 = max(0, i - w) # the window must stay inside the array 
        w1 = min(len(x), i + w)
        smoothed.append(sum(x[w0:w1])/(w1+w0))
    return np.array(smoothed)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just tested your solution. It does smooth the signal but not the way I want: gradually (more smoothing on the left, no smoothing on the right, like in the picture). Maybe I am missing something? I assumed w was window_length but maybe you had something else in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your update. Here is a working version:
def dynamic_smoothing(x, start_window_length=None, end_window_length=1):
    if not start_window_length:
        start_window_length = len(x)//2
    smoothed = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        # compute window length
        a = float(i) / len(x)
        w = int(np.round(a * start_window_length+(1.0-a) * end_window_length))
        # get the window
        w0 = max(0, i - w) # the window must stay inside the array 
        w1 = min(len(x), i + w)
        smoothed.append(sum(x[w0:w1])/(w1-w0))
    return np.array(smoothed)

Comment: The idea is great and it answers my question. You can just go ahead, remove the part of your answer above UPD and copy paste the code I'll modified and I'll accept the answer. Thank you very much! Note: linear decrease of the window length is not the best though but I'll modify this myself! The only drawback is that it is hard to enforce first point value and slope.

Comment: Beware, there are some errors in the accepted answer: start_window_length=(len(x)//2) must be put inside the function, d_sum is not used, a = float(i) / len(x), smoothed.append(sum(x[w0:w1])/(w1-w0)), last line is useless, start_window_length and end_window_length must be switched... I let this comment here for future users.